# Configuring GPG in Kmail

Tags: kubuntu, encryption, email, gnupg, kmail

Having done a fresh install I need to set this up again. We could do with an up to date guide. This might encourage more people to use encryption and signing.

I already have a keyring, but others need to know how to do that. That should probably be a separate question. I use KGPG to manage my keys.

In Kmail I know you need to set the default signing and encryption keys on your Identity.

When I try to sign an email it complains that signing failed without asking for my pass-phrase. What am I missing? How should I configure cryptography in Kmail?

Comment: What is the exact error when it fails?

Comment: Signing failed: Bad passphrase

Comment: Do you have pinentry (`pinentry-qt4`) installed? If so, by any chance does the password dialog pop up for a moment and immediately close itself once it gains focus?

Comment: did anyone happen to solve this? I have exactly the very same issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put

```
use-agent
```

in your ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf

I know because Seahorse used to put a blank file there and break things for people using GNOME & KDE together.  I wrote the patch that made it properly copy the skeleton file, but that wasn't until 2009.

Comment: I've done that and gpg-agent is installed. How do I make sure it is running?

Comment: ps -ef | grep agent

Comment: It's running. And I had pinentry-qt4 already.

Comment: Maybe I just needed another restart, but it's working now. Pinentry is popping up for my passphrase